# - I am trying to write a code where input should be abbbcc and output should be a1b3c2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, for-loop

- I am new to js.
- I am trying to write a code where input should be abbbcc and output should be a1b3c2.
- not sure how to get it
- providing code below

```or-tag-here
var word = "abbbcc";
var countword = [];

for (i=0; i < word.length; i++) {

    if (word[i] === charAt && word[i] != word[i+1]) {

        countword.push(word[i]);
        countword.push(i++);
    }

    else (word[i] === charAt && word[i] != word[i+1]) {

        countword.push(word[i]);
        for (i=0; i < word.length; i++) {
            if (word[i+1] === word[i+2]) {
                        countword.push(i++);
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }

    }


}

console.log("result----->" + countword);
```

Comment: You should be more explicit about what your algorithm is meant to do and what the expected inputs are. eg is it just giving the letter count or is it describing the string? What shoudl the result be for "aabbaacc"? Should it be "a4b2c3" or "a2b2a2c2"? Do you need to validate the input to make sure it fits the format you want? As it is your specification of "output should be a1b3c2" could be satisfied by "return "a1b2c3" though this is clearly now what you want (presuambly). When asking questions try to be thorough about describing the general case as well as specific examples.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using a `for` loop and a counter like this.

```js
var word = "abbbcc";
var countword = "";
var counter = 1;

for (i=0; i < word.length; i++) {

  if ( word[i] != word[i+1]) {

    // Save the letter and the counter
    countword += word[i]+counter;
    // Reset the counter
    counter=1;

  }else{
    // Increment counter
    counter++;
  }

}

console.log("result-----> " + countword );
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you put this line in simpler terms     countword += word[i]+counter; hard to understand

Comment: `countword += word[i]+counter;` is the exact same thing as `countword = countword+ word[i]+counter;` ;)

Comment: hello can you help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600110/minimise-the-code-since-i-am-using-the-same-code-only-the-content-in-p-tags-chan

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution using `Array#reduce`. I've described each step, I hope you will get my point and understand how does it works.

```js
var word = "abbbcc".split(''),
    res = '',
    counter = 1;

word.reduce(function(s, a, i, r) {
  if (s !== a) {  //if the succeeding element doesn't match the previous one
    res += s + counter; //concat it to the string + the amount of appearances (counter)
    counter = 1; //reset the counter
  } else {
    counter++; //the succeeding element matches the previous one, increment the counter
  }
  if (i === r.length - 1 && counter > 0) { //if the loop is over
    res += s + counter; //add the last element
  }
  return a;
})

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @texirv I'm sorry my friend but I'm not that much into React :(

Comment: hey thanks for your reply....you can also tell me in normal js...some problem here   render() {
        console.log("render");
        // debugger;


    var children = React.Children.map(
            this.props.children, this.enhanceSection);

    console.log("children----->" + JSON.stringify(children));

    return (
      <div className="accordion">
        <p> testing </p>
          {children}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

Comment: @texirv Try with string literal: function render() {
  var children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, this.enhanceSection);
  return `<div className="accordion"><p>testing</p>${{children}}</div>`;
}

Comment: hey thanks for your reply...but it didnt work...updated the code in the fiddle :(   http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/82/

Comment: @texirv You have to use it without `function` keyword. http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/84/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142989/discussion-between-texi-rv-and-kind-user).

Comment: but still its throwing this error in your fiddle Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Accordion.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: can you tell me how to fix it...I tried its not working :(